# Firebase notifications - subscribing to topics using iOS FCM token failing all the time... using C# API

Tags: c#, android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an App - Android and iOS with a partial web view.

I'm using a C# API back end and notifications via Firebase Cloud messaging works fine for Android, especially subscribing and unsubscribing to topics using the "registered" FM token.

Every time I try to subscribe to a topic using a FCM token that comes from an iOS device it fails.

I'm using very simple code to add tokens to topics e.g.

using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/" + [fcmToken] + "/rel/topics/" + [topic name]))
{

```
httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", [server key]);
httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sender", [sender id]);
httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //success
    }
    else
    {
       //failed
    }
}
```

}

Has anyone had any experience like this or a solution that I'm missing as to why iOS tokens are not getting subscribed to topics?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as your code works fine for Android, but not for iOS I would follow the differences you need to pay attention to:

- Did you initialize Firebase correctly for iOS? You might need to manually map your APN token to the Firebase token (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)
- Did you upload the APN certificate to Firebase? (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs)
- Do you correctly use the Notification Center if you want to display notifications?

Comment: Suggested checks have been investigated - presumed to be configured correct. Sadly still getting false trying to add to topics using iOS tokens. Only difference I see is how the token looks between iOS and Android. Working Android token: (dIXd6ZHVyy4:APA91bEO_Xkn9pw8L8gKPRnFDZmVmN5ywyWCrS84uNo8-JwJWq167RjYT4lvhr91DTlEcAbX1k9x4ZsuZvIENBt0evax2RkPhlRdqJUYFtqczl1FuOgCPZIcp13KSFljLseFBZWqIpcB). iOS token (not working): (73FF6FC7BE399395209088B2652468C4E251DD3CDED250342FD1DA2906BF5876). Has anyone else got any suggestions or had a similar issue they managed to resolve? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help, whenever I implemented Firebase notifications, I used native code, which worked when following the instructions... :/